# Missing modulation in IR signal?

Tags: infrared

I have a cheap IR remote control from Ebay (like [this](https://www.ebay.de/i/264851961712?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=707-134425-41852-0&mkcid=2&itemid=264851961712&targetid=857931346246&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9044665&poi=&campaignid=10215338563&mkgroupid=105782597247&rlsatarget=pla-857931346246&abcId=1139676&merchantid=7364532&gclid=CjwKCAjw19z6BRAYEiwAmo64LYVgfRYMezCm6lKzPOqRjFNvsCWeTJB8rSodpUvf4_ZihZTNQbzcjhoCd9kQAvD_BwE) one) and I´m straggling with the modulation of the IR signal. I use an [BPV11F](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2046359.pdf?_ga=2.47133607.1694773805.1599630361-1911667290.1588568878) photo transistor as receiver and I get this signal with my scope

[image]

But this signal looks very identical to the signal which comes from my [TSOP38238](https://www.vishay.com/docs/82491/tsop382.pdf):

[image]

So I would expect to see some kind of modulation (the 38 kHz carrier signal) when I receive this signal over the photo transistor, like in this image.

[image]

My guess is that this cheap remote doesn´t use a modulation (is this possible?). Or do I have some misunderstanding?

Comment: do you own a TV with its own remote control?

Comment: Yeah. I can try it with this. Good hint. Thank you

Comment: All my cheap remotes work happily. You might like to see their modulation waveforms: 
(1) "Rpi3 LIRC Library and UART IR Transceiver Setup Problem":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103452/rpi3-lirc-library-and-uart-ir-transceiver-setup-problem/103465#103465. Cheers.

Comment: Look at the top waveform : you see a very fast turn-on (falling edge) and a very slow turn-off (rising edge). That says your phototransistor is turning off very slowly : you haven't shown its schematic but I'm guessing the pull-up resistor is far too high to respond fast enough to show the 38kHz carrier. Try a 1K to 10K pullup.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you for the tip. Changing the collector resistor to 1k "solves" my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'd have expected to see some 38 kHz carrier signal too.
Brian Drummond has guessed a likely cause, where the phototransistor detector has too-limited bandwidth to see the carrier frequency (perhaps 36kHz - 56kHz). It is difficult to see the rise time of the oscilloscope plot, but a guess is: 20us. Besides, photo transistors have slow response time when load resistance is chosen too-high:
[image: phototransistor detector frequency response OPA505]

A phototransistor load resistor \$R_L\$ should be chosen *small enough* so that 40kHz is within the passband. A larger-value load resistor limits frequency response so that carrier frequency is not seen. That BPV11F phototransistor data sheet says that you should get 100kHz bandwidth with a 100 ohm \$R_L\$, but that low value might give you a rather insensitive detector.

In addition, when probing \$R_L\$ with an oscilloscope probe, you should choose **X10 attenuator** setting, rather than **X1 attenuator**. The additional capacitance of **X1** probe in parallel with \$R_L\$ will reduce frequency response even more.
Your phototransistor detector circuit may have such limited bandwidth, that it serves as a crude demodulator, yielding an output that looks similar to a proper IR-remote detector chip.

Comment: I agree with Brian. That is a phototransistor and the circuit used to measure this is unknown. Most likely the charges at the phototransistor base junction just don't discharge fast enough to see the 38kHz modulation and the transistor is on for long time for each 38kHz pulse. The remote surely has a carrier, if the TSOP receiver can receive it, and the carrier is most likely 38kHz as the remote appears to use NEC protocol. If a photodiode, or even a standard red LED (due to lack of better detector) is fed with IR pulses, the scope would show the 38kHz carrier.